# Htaccess Url Redirect Regex

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Incoming URL
`attorneys/attorney_detail.php?AttorneyID=23&Source=Title&Title=Partner`

Output URL `/attorney/static-name-here/`

I tried many ways of doing the redirect but it doesn't match correctly, just want to `ID=##` part with `attorneys/attorney_detail.php` part to be there.

This is what I have so far..
I want to remove the trailing query string.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} AttorneyID=23 [NC]
rewriterule ^attorneys/attorney_detail.php http://www.web.com/attorney/name-here/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)AttorneyID=23(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^attorneys/attorney_detail\.php$ /attorney/name-here/? [R=301,L,NC]
```

`?` in the will strip off any existing query string.